# Not able to select a default value in DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdownlist which I am populating using data from a table.

Then assigning it to a ViewBag and binding to element in HTML.

I am not able set a value by default; even if I am providing static value.
Here's my code-

**cs**

```
ViewBag.parent_categories = new SelectList(all_categories, "ID", "Category", "1");
```

**cshtml**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EOn, @ViewBag.parent_categories as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

But the result is that the selected value is blank always.

What is wrong in it?

Comment: What is the value of model.EOn? Because when you call DropDownListFor, the selected value of your list will be the value of the model property.

Comment: This is my answer. I was providing different value to EOn

Comment: Should these both values must match?

Comment: There is two ways of building your dropdown, either call DropDownList, and provide a SelectList with a default value, or call DropDownListFor, and provide a SelectList. In the second case, the selected value will be the value of your model property

Comment: Yeaa it makes sense! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have defined a person viewmodel-

```
namespace DropDownList.ViewModel
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int selectedPersonID { get; set; }
        //your other props
    }
}
```

Now on view define the `dropdownlistfor`

```
@model DropDownList.ViewModel.Person

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedPersonID, 
{new SelectListItem(){ Value="0", Text= "--Please select a Person--"} )
```

In case if you use `DropDownList` then the syntax is bit different.

```
@Html.DropDownList("slPerson", Model.PersonList, Model.SelectedPersonID)
```

and the corresponding viewmodel structure will be

```
@model namespace.MyViewModel 

public class MyViewmodel {

  public List<SelectListItem> PersonList {get; set}
  public string SelectedPersonID {get; set}

  public MyViewModel(){
      PersonList = new List<SelectListItem>();
      SelectedPersonID  = "100"; //default values go here
  }
```

Hope this clears the doubt.